# Why does dig utility hang indefinitely even with timeout specified?

Tags: dns, timeout, dig

I'm using `dig` utility to find public IP address.

The command I used is:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

but I had problem since on some other computers it took so long, so I added a **timeout after 5 seconds**:

```
dig +short +time=5 +tries=1 myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

and it fails on some as expected, but on some other computers it never finishes. All it does is hangs...

Any idea why and how can this be fixed to timeout after 5 seconds as expected ?

EDIT:

Already tried `timeout` but it still hangs. I think it stucks while resolving DNS. For example, I can't `ping www.google.com`, but can `172.217.20.4`.

Answer (score 5):

As for using aplicational timeouts in some utilities, when there are connectivity issues, it is not always guaranteed the application will stop on it's own with some outside "coercion".

I would use an external utility to kill it after some time just in case, for the problematic situations where it hangs.

As in:

```
timeout 5 dig +short +time=5 +tries=1 myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

From `man timeout`

> NAME         top
>
> ```
>    timeout - run a command with a time limit
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>    timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
>    timeout [OPTION]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION         top
>
> ```
>    Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
> ```

Comment: I suspect 5s can be slow in some situation, but I do not know the OPs network.

Comment: I already tried `timeout`, but it still hangs. I don't know why...

Comment: I think it stucks while resolving DNS. I can't `ping www.google.com`, but can `172.217.20.4`

Comment: timelimit might work better. Will add it as an alternative when i get to my Debian machine.

Comment: (At least FreeBSD and GNU) timeout has a -k option to SIGKILL after an additional time.